Is there a difference between the verbs “book” and “prebook”?
I have been seeing the term "prebook" used in business conference marketing. Here’s an example: “Be sure to prebook your one-on-one consultation with a product expert ...”
Is that any different from saying "Be sure to book your one-on-one consultation ..."?
Merriam-Webster defines “prebook” as "to book (something) in advance.” At the same time, the various definitions for “book” all suggest the scheduling of something in advance. The first definition, for example, says "to register (something, such as a name) for some future activity or condition ..."
Am I missing something? Does "pre-" give extra emphasis — sort of like saying, "Don’t wait until the last minute”? Or is “pre-” here just a superfluous prefix?
